# c++ code for linear regression with cost function and gradiant descent

Tags: c++, r

here is my work

```
#include<iostream.h>
using namespace std;

void gradiantFunction(x,y,th0,th1,a)
{
double temp0,temp1;
for (int i = 0; i < m.size(); i++)
{
    h=th0+th1*x[i];
    temp0=temp0+(h-y[i]);
    temp1=temp1+(h-y[i])*x[i];
   /* delta = y[i]-hypothesis(x[i]);
    theta[1] += alpha*delta*x[i];
    theta[0] += alpha*delta*1;*/
}
temp0=temp0*a/m;
temp1=temp1*a/m;
}

void CostFunction(x,y,th0,th1,a)
{
double temp2=0;
for (int i = 0; i < m.size(); i++)
{
    h=th0+th1*x[i];
    temp2=temp2+(h-y[i]);
}
double j=temp2/(2*m);
}

void main()
{
double a=0.01, th0=0.1, th1=0.2, temp0,temp1, jHistory[];
int m=1500;
for(int i=1; i<=m;i++)
{
    th0=th0-temp0;
    th1=th1-temp1;

    double j= CostFunction()
    double jHistory[i]=j;
}
```

i want the code to learn these values of thetas

```
 - 6.1101   17.592
 - 5.5277   9.1302
 - 8.5186   13.662
 - 7.0032   11.854
 - 5.8598   6.8233
 - 8.3829   11.886
 - 7.4764   4.3483
 - 8.5781   12
 - 6.4862   6.5987
 - 5.0546   3.8166
 - 5.7107   3.2522
 - 14.164   15.505
 - 5.734    3.1551
 - 8.4084   7.2258
 - 5.6407   0.71618
 - 5.3794   3.5129
 - 6.3654   5.3048
 - 5.1301   0.56077
 - 6.4296   3.6518
 - 7.0708   5.3893
 - 6.1891   3.1386
 - 20.27    21.767
 - 5.4901   4.263
 - 6.3261   5.1875
 - 5.5649   3.0825
 - 18.945   22.638
 - 12.828   13.501

10.957  7.0467
13.176  14.692
22.203  24.147
5.2524  -1.22
6.5894  5.9966
9.2482  12.134
5.8918  1.8495
8.2111  6.5426
7.9334  4.5623
8.0959  4.1164
5.6063  3.3928
12.836  10.117
6.3534  5.4974
5.4069  0.55657
6.8825  3.9115
11.708  5.3854
5.7737  2.4406
7.8247  6.7318
7.0931  1.0463
5.0702  5.1337
5.8014  1.844
11.7    8.0043
5.5416  1.0179
7.5402  6.7504
5.3077  1.8396
7.4239  4.2885
7.6031  4.9981
6.3328  1.4233
6.3589  -1.4211
6.2742  2.4756
5.6397  4.6042
9.3102  3.9624
9.4536  5.4141
8.8254  5.1694
5.1793  -0.74279
21.279  17.929
14.908  12.054
18.959  17.054
7.2182  4.8852
8.2951  5.7442
10.236  7.7754
5.4994  1.0173
20.341  20.992
10.136  6.6799
7.3345  4.0259
6.0062  1.2784
7.2259  3.3411
5.0269  -2.6807
6.5479  0.29678
7.5386  3.8845
5.0365  5.7014
10.274  6.7526
5.1077  2.0576
5.7292  0.47953

5.1884  0.20421
6.3557  0.67861
9.7687  7.5435
6.5159  5.3436
8.5172  4.2415
9.1802  6.7981
6.002   0.92695
5.5204  0.152
5.0594  2.8214
5.7077  1.8451
7.6366  4.2959
5.8707  7.2029
5.3054  1.9869
8.2934  0.14454
13.394  9.0551
5.4369  0.61705
```

Comment: Use `static const` array of `pair<double, double>`?  Use an input file? Search the web for "neural net machine learning c++".

Comment: What is your question exactly? What does not work?

Comment: Shouldn't you pass th0 and th1 as reference in gradiantFunction and then update it at the end (instead of updating temp0, temp1)?